# Odata v.4 $filter for the DateTime Calendar Events in the Office 365 REST API

Tags: rest, odata, uri, ms-office, office365

I am trying to get and filter Calendar events from the Office 365 REST API with the following query:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/user@user.com/calendars/AAAAAAAAAAA/events?$top=100&$select=BodyPreview&$filter=Start ge 2016-02-10T22:00:00Z
```

So I want 100 results with only the BodyPreview as return value for all Events greater than 2016-02-10 22:00:00.

The Error Message I receive is this one:

```
ERROR request returned 400
error:
code: 'RequestBroker-ParseUri',
message: 'A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types \'Microsoft.OutlookServices.DateTimeTimeZone\' and \'Edm.DateTimeOffset\' for operator kind \'GreaterThanOrEqual\'.'
```

The query without the filter option works flawlessly. So how do I get my query to represent a 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.DateTimeTimeZone' type?

I had a look at this post:
[Odata $filter for the date in the Office 365 REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574361/odata-filter-for-the-date-in-the-office-365-rest-api)

But I can not see the difference between my query and the one in the post.

And all examples on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar do not mention this type of DateTimeTimeZone query in the examples.

I also tried this query format:

```
datetime'2016-01-10T22:00:00'
```

Also no luck.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type for `Start` and `End` [changed in the beta and v2 endpoints](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/10/14/outlook-rest-api-changes-to-beta-endpoint-part-ii.aspx). It's now a complex type, so you need to change your filter a bit:

```
$filter=Start/DateTime ge 2016-02-10T22:00:00Z
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason for the quick response, unfortunately I still get the same error message :( this is the query I used `/events?$top=100&$select=BodyPreview&$filter=Start/DateTime ge 2016-02-10T22:00:00Z`

Comment: I needed to put the DateTime within quotes to make it work `$filter=Start/DateTime eq \'2015-09-25T09:00:00\'` Now it works, thanks again @Jason!

Comment: Gotcha. Note that you can also use `CalendarView` to get all events in a specified window of time, which has the added benefit of expanding recurring events for you (if that fits what you're trying to achieve, of course!)

Comment: thank you Jason. I don't believe this was well documented in API.

Comment: Thx user263367! It was the two backslashes I missed (\'2015-09-25T09:00:00\'). Spent several hours before I found this post..